# How to determine the WhatsApp file name format for pictures?

Tags: android, whatsapp

**Premise:** I am using WhatsApp on Android.

### Why I am asking this

I am trying to create a script that, when configured with proper arguments, would restore accidentally deleted pictures in a WhatsApp chat, if you have a copy of those files somewhere else (with potentially different file names) and you pass them to the script.

### What happens when you delete an image

Normally, if you accidentally delete the image files, WhatsApp still shows you a thumbnail, but if you click on it the following pop-up appears.

[image: Missing-file]

Therefore, I guess it looks for a filename in the storage and it tries to load that file.

### I verified this

I tested this by manually replacing an image in the "WhatsApp Images" folder with another image, and the new image shows up in the corresponding chat as expected, so this is right.

*But* when I did that test, I knew the file name because I manually watched the file previews using a file manager and I identified the right file, so that was easy.

### So the problem is

What about **deleted files**? how can I try to guess the corresponding file names in order to place the file copy back where it is supposed to be?

### What I already know

First of all, I know the file names have this format:

```
IMG-yyyymmdd-WAxxxx.jpg
```

Where yyyymmmmdd is a date and xxxx is a sort of sequence number.

I also know that the mapping from thumbnails to actual files is stored in the `msgstore.db` database file, but it can only be accessed if you have root privileges. Do you think is there any other way to predict what the file name can be without accessing that DB?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answers to similar topics. I compressed my video archive as low resolution and over-wrote them. It worked as you said. When you want to follow up the file with related messages to understand/remember the concept/situation/circumstances it works.

If possible, I believe WhatsApp will change its media management soon. Because we don't need any space on mobile phones if we also keep them on the cloud. And we should be able to edit files in our cloud folders.